# Do manually installed programs/packages get updates automatically?

Tags: 18.04, apt, 20.04, filesystem

I downloaded android studio as a .tar.gz into home directory on ubuntu 20.04 and then I discovered that downloaded software is conventionally put in /opt directory. So now if I cut/paste the whole directory than contains the android studio files into /opt will it automatically get updates when I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

The question also applies to any package installed outside of snap and apt

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` works for packages.deb installed with `apt, dpkg, gdebi` only. .... Manually installed files are unknown to the "package data base".

Comment: `apt-get` is not magical. It cannot know how to upgrade random cut/paste software that was never part of a deb package.

Comment: @user535733 I thougt that it(snap) searches for packages in specific folder like /opt and there it searches for updates for all that packages as it will think that everything there is installed by it

Comment: No, because a .tar.gz file *is not a package*. It's just a random file. Snapd is also not magical -- it does not know where random files come from. It only knows where snap-packaged files come from.

Comment: @user535733 you are saying things on my behalf, I am not a linux pro but also not that stupid :)
when I say android studio folder how did you understand that I mean that I copied the compressed file? I meant I copied the extracted folder which is btw the same folder that will be installed by apt-get or snap, that's why I thought snap or apt will search for any package's folder with a specific hierarchy and update that package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `apt-get upgrade` only updates packages that were installed through apt.

Comment: Then when android studio (or any other app for example) at their official website download their app as a tar.gz package how do they expect me to update it? Should I just check each app installed this way manually at their website if there is a newer version?

Comment: @HaidarMehsen, if you install it manually, then you are expected to update it manually. One of the conveniences of using software *packages* (like debs) is a package manager (like apt) than can handle routine maintenance (like updates) for you.